# How to reuse existing RDBMS JPA entities (Java Classes) on NoSQL DB

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, rdbms, nosql

I have created a JPA desktop application with MySQL as DB. And I have configured the persistence.xml file as, it will create the tables in DB, if the tables are not already present (`<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />`). This application is working fine so far. But, I am planning to publish this application in Cloud, so that everyone can get benefit of this application.

My assumption is, when it gets popular (being optimistic), I believe, the data will grow to greater extend. So I am planning to use NoSQL instead of RDBMS for scalability purpose. But I am not a NoSQL developer so far.

**My Question is, Can I reuse the existing JPA2.0 Entities (auto-generated code, created using EclipseLink in Eclipse neon) pointing to NoSQL, by simply changing the values in persistence.xml file?** Will it work as it is working currently?

Comment: Do You remeber, NoSQL have no features of relation DB? Must use very low features. Eclipselink knowledge base have article (don't have link, but I had read)

Comment: And next. I think one of most important NoSQL have not so strict integrity / consistency rules, i.e. very important word "eventual consistency". Many strict algorithms like bookkeeping are non portable to such database.

Comment: But, is there any possibility to implement my question for tables without any relationship in rdbms?

Comment: It depends. Let imagine what is Entity project rage, show classes, lets speak

Comment: Interesting reading for every NoSQL port https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

Comment: If You don't have relations in Your data, probably beginning JPA/MySQL selection was wrong. My EOT without code